# Jquery show/hide post menu

Tags: jquery

I've been trying for a couple of days to figure this out myself but without luck.
It needs to show post with same attr as the menu a.

http://jsfiddle.net/MatsKruger/CeLkt/

Hope you guys can help

Best regards

Comment: It's that when i click on the menu all shows and then som of them hides again.
The functionality works if i remove the all script.
So basicly i want the menu to show the posts with the the same class as the menus title attr. but when i try to make them all show with the all a tag it show every post and then hide the ones without the class.

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that after you click old items (the ones without the class) are only hidden after the ones with the class are shown? for that you just need to flip the hide and show statements.

Comment: Yea but then it won't look at the attr right.
It needs to show the posts with the class which is the same as the nav element.
The only thing thats not working is the if statement if i remove the if then it will work just fint but then i don't have an all button to show everything.
I think it would be easier to just fade them 50% out so you still can see the post but they aren't active.
Would that be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CeLkt/3/)? If you want to achieve a %50 fade effect then instead of hiding and showing you can add and remove a `CSS` class to the posts.